# Singleton form: how to handle the case when form is "disposed"

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to implement a "Popup" information form, which should be shown at various occasions (like mouse over, context menu, etc), and which should automatically hide when the user changes the focus.

I decided to do it with the SINGLETON pattern, like this:

```
public class frmCellInfo : Form
{
    public static frmCellInfo instance; 

    public static frmCellInfo GetInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new frmCellInfo();
        return instance;
    }

    private frmCellInfo() // PRIVATE, because of Singleton
    {
         InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmCellInfo_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
    }

    // ......
```

The form is called like this:

```
frmCellInfo frm = frmCellInfo.GetInstance();
frm.Show();
```

Basically, the automatic show/hide works like intended; however, when the user CLOSES the form by clicking the "X" icon, **then the form goes, and next time, when I try to acces the form, I get the exception "Cannot access a disposed object"**

So in way, the instance is still "there", but "disposed" (?)

**Question:** How should I rewrite the call of the form or the singleton pattern, so that in case the form is "disposed", I can create it again?

Comment: I think that Singleton purpose is creating one instance of element per application lifetime, not to recreate it after it is disposed.

Comment: What advantages / gains do you expect from having a single dialog form instance?

Comment: @flq Since this form is shown very often, I was assuming that is is much quicker to just show and hide the form, instead of constantly disposing and re-creating it. Might be a wrong assumption ?

Comment: You could overwrite the method which is called by clicking the "X" button to hide the window and not destrying it

Comment: @Giosco - disposing object means getting rid of resources it was using. I don't think your popup is such a resources demanding element that it needs special treatment.

Comment: @al-eax I am always hesitating to override the close event, because I have seen situations where such code might block the whole application from closing. (e.g. when the computer is shut down.)

Comment: this code is also not thread safe FYI.

Comment: I am not sure, but you could have a look at the `showDialog` method. I think this it allows to reopen the form again.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not what forms meant for! you should use forms as they supposed to be used. Odd usage leads mostly to odd behavior and unexpected exceptions, and of course, dirty code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reference `frmCellInfo.instance` is not null,
when you tried to open form after it was closed by `X` button (Disposed)

Then method `frmCellInfo.GetInstance()` return reference to the disposed instance.

Set it to null in the `FormClosed` eventhandler

```
private void frmCellInfo_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    frmCellInfo.instance = null;
}
```

Then in the method `frmCellInfo.GetInstance()` new instance will be created as you wanted

Comment: Ah yes of course, that's a good method!! Very simple, and I like the fact that the closing cannot block the whole application or a shutdown. BTW: I'd rather use `Form_Closed` instead of `Form_Closing` ?

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer is: you shouldn't. [Jon Skeet's description of the Singleton pattern](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx) is quite apt:

> Essentially, a singleton is a class which **only allows a single instance** of itself to be created, and usually gives simple access to that instance.

A Form is possibly a poor candidate for a singleton instance - its state may change and you may need to show the form more than once. From my personal experience, the best candidates for singleton instances are classes which **could** be static, but either inherit another class or have to implement one or more interfaces. A `Form` doesn't fit those criteria very well.

> So in way, the instance is still "there", but "disposed" (?)

Yes, if you really wanted to you could `catch` the `ObjectDisposedException` in your `GetInstance` method and re-create the instance of the form. This isn't the way to do it and actually goes against the whole idea of a singleton. Think twice whether you really want to follow the pattern before implementing a hack like this.

Comment: In fact, this form is a kind of custom tooltip. Since it is shown very often, I was assuming that is is much quicker to just show and hide the form, instead of constantly disposing and re-creating it. That's why I took a singleton pattern.

Comment: @Giosco - Singleton is meant to create only one instance of element per application lifetime(such a factory, logger etc) - after disposing you are not  supposed to use it anymore.

Comment: @Giosco There are ways around it, Anton Kedrov's answer provides one, and I've edited my answer to include one as well. Do consider not using a singleton if you're forced to hack around it to make it work though.

Comment: Yeah, I am for sure against "hacks", they often become boomerangs. Better to stay with standardized procedures.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve it by canceling `FormClosing` event and hiding the form.

[CancelEventArgs.Cancel Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs.Cancel);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

```
    private void frmCellInfo_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.Hide();
    }
```

Comment: But what happens if the whole application is closed, or when shutting down the computer? Could this block the application from closing ?

Comment: @Giosco What exactly are you trying to achieve?! process termination and killing when shutting down closes every thing!

Comment: This will not block the app from closing. All objects will be disposed as soon as you close the main form. If you concerned about disposing this form, then it is possible to do it manually in, for example, the main form closing event.